# Generate reports with selenium grid and cucumber

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, cucumber-junit

I am trying to integrate Selenium grid and cucumber.

I am currently stuck in a situation where I want to execute my testscripts on the distributed system with the different browser configured as node.

When the execution is triggered the hub redirects the test script to a node as specified in desired capabilities. But once the execution is completed I don't see the result generated as HTML report.

The test scripts do not execute in parallel.Please suggest if any configuration is missing or any custom code needs to be developed for capturing the result of execution on node.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use JUnit.
Use @After tag and you could write the results in a csv file with the required parameters and scenario name.

Answer (score 0):

## 1 continuous integration

Most of company integrate automation test with Jenkins and after every build test execute from jenkins and decide build is pass or fail and send result to team.

Here You can use gradle and integrate with Jenkins and There is plugin already available for cucumber plugin is [Github Link](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Jenkins-integration)

Integration Gradle with Jenkins : [Github Link](https://gradle.org/gradle-and-jenkins/)

## 2

You can use Junit integration with cucumber and here is step by step :
http://damienfremont.com/2015/07/30/how-to-cucumber-test-reporting-plugin-with-maven-and-java/

## 3

You can use log4j and integrate with Selenium atuomation framework and produce custom report
http://www.guru99.com/tutorial-on-log4j-and-logexpert-with-selenium.html

## 5

Create custom excel sheet report
http://seleniummaster.com/sitecontent/index.php/selenium-web-driver-menu/selenium-test-automation-with-java/167-write-selenium-webdriver-testng-result-to-excel-file

> I would prefer number 1 continuous integration